# Is there really no delete or cut?

Tags: modeling

So I made a fin on my fish that I don't like. So in every app existing I select and delete.

In real sculpture I just cut off or carve away.

How do I do this in Blender?

I tried selecting vertices in edit but it won't mirror so it becomes asymetric. I have used booleans but the remaining surface becomes super wierd when I want to smooth it out to get a fresh start.

Select + delete in sculpt.

Or even better, a carve tool that eats away chunks and not leaving wierd remains.

[image]

Comment: did you try to use the "flatten" tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete selected vertices/edges/faces by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd>.
To make the selection symmetrical, use either *Mirror selection* or a *Mirror modifier*

*Mirror selection across X axis*

[image]

Comment: deleting nodes/faces in this way will create some strange artifacts since the new topology has to be fixed (but it should be easy to sculpt some more to fix the remaining surfaces)

Comment: I don't sculpt that much, so feel free to post a more appropriate answer :). This is just a quick overview.

Comment: thanks for taking time!:) I got it now "mask slice and fill holes" I don't know if this is a 2.82 thing since I just updated but it kind of worked!